# What type of micro-USB is used?

Tags: power-supply

From previous experience I've discovered there are quite a few different types of micro-USB connectors.

Here are three main ones:

[image: USB connectors]

I'm pretty sure it's not the middle one; and I *think* it's the **left** one, but better safe than sorry.

So is it the one I suspect?

Comment: @PeterMortensen done

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is the left hand one.

The right hand one is a mini-USB (rather than micro) and the centre one appears to be somewhat non-standard.

Comment: Correct; the connector in the middle is one used for digital cameras and other stuff.  The one on the left is the only one that should *ever* be called "micro USB".  In fact, that image you provided is a cropped version of the Wikipedia image of USB connector comparisons @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Usb_connectors.JPG -- and the middle one is listed as "UC-E6 proprietary (not USB)", which is proprietary to Nikon.